# How to compile "Hello World" in C++ with Ninja?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, compilation, ninja

I'm new with Ninja. Still don't know how to use it.

I created a simple `hello.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I am using Linux Ubuntu.

I have installed CMake with: `apt install cmake`

and I have installed ninja: `apt-get install ninja-build`

But now what should I do to compile my `hello.cpp` file with Ninja?

I tried to run `ninja` but I'm getting error about `rules.ninja`:

```
ninja: error: build.ninja:30: loading 'rules.ninja': No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to create `rules.ninja` and how to configure it, and I don't know if I miss more things.

Comment: What does your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like? And how are you invoking `cmake`?

Comment: I don't have CMakeLists.txt or cmake file.
How do I create them? I have always used makefile to generate my c++ projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming here that you do not have a `CMakeLists.txt` file at all. To compile this program, you first need to create a `CMakeLists.txt` file. This file is used by CMake to configure the project.

`CMakeLists.txt` (place it in the same folder as your source files):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # Try 11 if your compiler does not support C++14
add_executable(my_exe hello.cpp)
```

Then you need to invoke CMake (in the terminal, go to the folder containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file) and later build the project.

First, you should create a build directory. This is handy since you don't want to mix build output with your project files.

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Then, you invoke CMake and tell it to generate a Ninja build system (`-GNinja`), while at the same time tell it where the `CMakeLists.txt` file is located (`..`), which should be directly below the `build` folder:

```
cmake -GNinja ..
```

Now, you are ready to build the executable:

```
ninja
```

Done. You should now have an executable name `my_exe` in your `build` folder.